# How to get a image as <ul type style>?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Style

```
<style>
  ul{
    list-style-image: url('../8iAbk7rjT.png');
  }
</style>
```

Coding

```
<ul>
  <asp:DataList ID="dd" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><a href="/Pages/index.aspx?category=<%#Eval("id") %>">
          <%#Eval("name") %></a></li>
        <hr />
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
</ul>
```

How to Get an image As `UL` style in asp.net.
   Any solution??

Comment: Do you mean you want to use an image for the bullet point?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to do in asp.net for this. It's CSS matter. Your code is fine, just check for image url whether it's correct or not.

```
ul{
   list-style-image: url('http://forums.androidcentral.com/images/smilies/cool.png');
   padding: 0 0 0 30px;
   margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```